# Custom Innosetup page with custom buttons

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to create a custom Innosetup page which has the following layout. That will be displayed as the very first page and if user clicks the Configure button, he will be taken to the typical install pages. if user clicks the Install button, the install will happen silently.

```
+------------------------------------+
|                                    |
|                                    |
|        a bitmap image              |
|                                    |
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
Cancel               Install Configure
```

It looks like custom pages and forms do not allow that. Is this possible with Innosetup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my first answer I didn't really see the requirement for additional buttons.

I think you can not do this with InnoSetup, but you could actually create a "wrapper" application that shows your page and upon the "Install" button click runs the InnoSetup setup.

---

Searching SO a bit more, I found there's actually a way of *adding* your own buttons to the UI as described in the answer to this question: [Inno Setup - replace default next/back/cancel buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868236/inno-setup-replace-default-next-back-cancel-buttons). I don't know, however, if there's also a way of removing unwanted buttons.

It is stated in this answer that there are examples in the CodeClasses.iss example script in \program files\inno setup 5\examples.

Comment: Eh, what first answer ? And why would you create a application for this ? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: I wrote a first version of my answer thinking you didn't know how to create pages for InnoSetup. This is the second (edited) answer. I don't understand why that doesn't make sense to you, actually. Given that InnoSetup can not create a "page" that replaces the setup buttons, too, a small wrapper application that shows the desired user interface and then launches the setup is a proper way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked the answer was edited. But still I don't like anything external for this purpose. You can simulate standard button clicks by firing their `OnClick` events or even better, you can run the very same setup with `/SILENT` parameter by a install button click.

Comment: Would you mind writing an answer elaborating on this? I don't quite know what you're aiming at...

Comment: A "Launcher" is also common when, for example, run from a CD.