# Inno setup: add button on components page

Tags: inno-setup

I've been surfing the net and I came across this site.

I need help with my setup: I'd like to create a button, as I show in the image attached, that when users click it, it appears an information panel.

Thanks so much in advanced.

http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/sin-titulo-1-920233.gif

Comment: Here is [`a list of answers`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Binno-setup%5D+TNewButton.Create+is%3Aanswer) where the answerers create buttons. I'm sure you'll find the way there.

Comment: Thanks for this, one of them is good for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868236/inno-setup-replace-default-next-back-cancel-buttons/4868623#4868623 but I only need the button in the components page

Comment: Then you need to include [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/YUdAEfx9).

Comment: Thanks but I've been trying that for the last hour, no luck. I got this error http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/sin-titulo-920484.png 
This is the code I have http://pastebin.com/3zFWrbDS
Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: That happened because you've tried to access a not existing object, the `MyButton` variable. You can create it [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/PMcLcYw5) e.g.

Comment: Woohoo! This is working!! Thanks so much for the help. I cannot give you positive points yet :( but I will as soon as I can